# Iterating through child li nodes in xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
$page = '<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="this one">
            <h2>Ignore</h2>
            <p>Text</p>

            <h2>Header 1</h2>
            <ul><li>List Value 1</li></ul>

            <h2>Header 2</h2>
            <ul><li>List Value 2</li></ul>

            <h2>Ignore</h2>
            <ul><li>List Value 3</li></ul>

            <h2>Header 3</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>List Value A</li>
                <li>List Value B</li>
                <li>List Value C</li>
            </ul>

            <h2>Ignore</h2>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>';
```

I am trying to get the `li` list for `Header 3` only and the following code doesn't work;

```
$doc->loadHTML($page);   
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='this one']/h2[.='Header 3']/ul/li");
foreach($nodes as $node) { 
    echo $node->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
```

I am expecting the output:

```
List Value A<br />
List Value B<br />
List Value C<br />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expression that you want:

```
//div[@class = 'this one']/h2[text() = 'Header 3']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li
```

Broken down a bit:

- `//div[@class = 'this one']` - Match all `<div>`s in the document with the specified `class` attribute value
- `…/h2[text() = 'Header 3']` - Match all `<h2>`s that are children of those `<div>`s that have the specified text content
- `…/following-sibling::ul` - Use the `following-sibling` axis to match `<ul>`s that appear after the `<h2>`s
- `…[1]` - Match only the first `<ul>` that is a sibling of the matched `<h2>` (*… remembering that indexes are 1-based in XPath expressions*)
- `…/li` - And match all of the `<li>`s which are children of that `<ul>`

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski , because `ul` is not a child of `h2`, but its sibling

Comment: @Andersson oooohhh. This is why proper indentation is important ;)

Comment: I would also specify the index of list (`following-sibling::ul[1]`) in case there are more following headers and lists (e.g. `<h2>Header 4</h2><ul>...</ul>`) so that only *immediate sibling* will be fetched

Comment: @splash58, if I completely move the `<ul>` (without leaving a copy where it currently is), then I still see the same output. That appears to be wrong. I will work on it.